# How to configure the FTP root folder in Mac OS X El Capitan?

Tags: macos, mac, ftp

I know how to

- turn an FTP server on:

  ```
  sudo -s launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist
  ```
- turn the FTP server off:

  ```
  sudo -s launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist
  ```

The root FTP folder is automatically set to `/Users/my_username`.

How can I change the root FTP folder to a folder of my choice?

Comment: It's been a year. Have you made any progress on this srjohnhuang? I want to find this out for myself now.

Answer (score 1):

The FTP user's home folder is defined in the System Preferences "Users and Groups" app. Go to Apple Menu > System Preferences > Users and Groups.

The magic is using the [Control] + [Click] secret option. While holding down the [Control] key, click on the user in the list of users and the secret "Advanced Options" menu will appear. Change the user's home directory to whatever you want in the ensuing options screen.

Then when ever a service (SSH, FTP, etc.) logs in, this configured new home directory will be the starting point.

However, be very careful as any errors could cause the user to be unreachable / corrupted and if it's the only admin user on your system, you could lock yourself out permanently.

FURTHERMORE, it is strongly recommended that you setup a dedicated separate user for FTP. Not the main system user. This separate user would have the customized home directory.